# Not getting any plots and some errors for the optimization problem

Tags: python, optimization

This is my code and I cannot seem to get any plots and there always seems to be the same error no matter how many times I tried to change my code. I have also shown my errors below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import solve, cholesky
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from skopt import gp_minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gaussian_rbf(x, x_prime, beta):
    return np.exp(-beta * np.linalg.norm(x - x_prime)**2)

def construct_interpolation_matrix(nodes, beta):
    N = len(nodes)
    K = np.zeros((N, N))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            K[i, j] = gaussian_rbf(nodes[i], nodes[j], beta)
    return K

def conditioning_analysis(N, m, beta):
    nodes = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
    K = construct_interpolation_matrix(nodes, beta)

    selected_indices = np.random.choice(N, m, replace=False)
    selected_nodes = nodes[selected_indices]

    condition_full = np.linalg.cond(K)
    condition_partial = np.linalg.cond(K[selected_indices][:, selected_indices])

    return condition_full, condition_partial

def objective_function(x):
    x_scalar = np.atleast_1d(x)[0]
    return -(x_scalar**2 + np.sin(5 * x_scalar))

def gradient_hessian(x):
    df_dx = 2 * x * np.exp(-(1 - x)**2) - 4 * x * (1 - x) * np.exp(-(1 - x)**2)
    d2f_dx2 = -2 * np.exp(-(1 - x)**2) + 4 * x * (1 - x) * np.exp(-(1 - x)**2) - 4 * (1 - x) * np.exp(-(1 - x)**2)
    return df_dx, d2f_dx2

def optimize_with_newton(initial_guess, max_iter=10):
    x_opt = initial_guess
    for _ in range(max_iter):
        df_dx, d2f_dx2 = gradient_hessian(x_opt)
        x_opt = x_opt - df_dx / d2f_dx2
    return x_opt

def gaussian_process_optimization(initial_points, objective_function, bounds, n_iter=10):
    def objective_function_gp(X):
        return np.array([objective_function(x) for x in X])

    result = gp_minimize(objective_function_gp, bounds, acq_func="LCB", n_calls=n_iter + 1, random_state=42, x0=initial_points)
    return result.x[0]

# Task 1: Analyze conditioning
N = 10
m = 5
beta = 1.0
condition_full, condition_partial = conditioning_analysis(N, m, beta)
print(f"Conditioning for full matrix: {condition_full}")
print(f"Conditioning for partial matrix: {condition_partial}")

# Optimize with Newton's method
initial_guess_newton = 0.5
x_opt_newton = optimize_with_newton(initial_guess_newton)
print(f"Optimal solution with Newton's method: {x_opt_newton}")

# Gaussian process optimization
initial_points_gp = np.random.rand(5)
bounds_gp = [(0.0, 1.0)]

x_opt_gp = gaussian_process_optimization(initial_points_gp, objective_function, bounds_gp, n_iter=10)
print(f"Optimal solution with Gaussian process optimization: {x_opt_gp}")

# Compare methods
x_values = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
y_true = objective_function(x_values)

plt.plot(x_values, y_true, label="True Function")
plt.scatter(x_opt_newton, objective_function(x_opt_newton), color="red", label="Newton's Method")
plt.scatter(x_opt_gp, objective_function(x_opt_gp), color="green", label="Gaussian Process")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("f(x)")
plt.title("Comparison of Optimization Methods")
plt.show()
```

**I tried to fix the following code many times but I always get either of the error messages:
Error Type 1 that I keep getting now:**

```
 result = gp_minimize(objective_function_gp, bounds, acq_func="LCB", n_calls=n_iter + 1, random_state=42, x0=initial_points)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\gp.py:259 in gp_minimize
    return base_minimize(

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\base.py:266 in base_minimize
    raise RuntimeError("Optimization space (%s) and initial points in x0 "

RuntimeError: Optimization space (Space([Real(low=0.0, high=1.0, prior='uniform', transform='normalize')])) and initial points in x0 use inconsistent dimensions.
```

**Error Type 2 I get sometimes after trying to fix my code:**

```
  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\gp.py:259 in gp_minimize
    return base_minimize(

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\base.py:291 in base_minimize
    result = optimizer.tell(x0, y0)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\optimizer.py:482 in tell
    check_x_in_space(x, self.space)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skopt\utils.py:187 in check_x_in_space
    if not np.all([p in space for p in x]):

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skopt\utils.py:187 in <listcomp>
    if not np.all([p in space for p in x]):

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skopt\space\space.py:1035 in __contains__
    if component not in dim:

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\skopt\space\space.py:364 in __contains__
    return self.low <= point <= self.high

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Edit: I managed to get the plot in this way. However, now I can only see Newton on the graph but not the other process.

```
x_values = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
y_true = [objective_function(x) for x in x_values]
plt.plot(x_values, y_true, label="True Function")
plt.scatter(x_opt_newton, objective_function(x_opt_newton), color="red", label="Newton's Method")
plt.scatter(x_opt_gp, objective_function(x_opt_gp), color="green", label="Gaussian Process")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("f(x)")
plt.title("Comparison of Optimization Methods")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you give five bounds, `[(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0)]`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are trying to paralelize your optimization by running with five initial points and returning five function evaluations.

However, if you pass a vector as `x0`, this is interpreted as a n-dimensional vector. This is the cause of your first error: you are giving a "five-dimensional" vector but only one bound.

Your second error is a bit strange, but I narrowed it down to `gp_optimize()` requiring a Python list of numbers, not a NumPy array.

Then, you would get a third error, because the evaluation `func(x0)` needs to return a scalar, and it is currently returning a 5-vector.

So, `gp_optimize()` is not doing what you expected at all. You will need to give it one `x0` at a time and pass `optimize_function` directly.

I have this alternative for you:

```py
def gaussian_process_optimization(initial_points, objective_function, bounds, n_iter=10):
    ret = np.zeros(len(initial_points))
    for i, x0 in enumerate(initial_points):
        result = gp_minimize(objective_function, bounds, acq_func="LCB", n_calls=n_iter + 1, random_state=42, x0=[x0])
        ret[i] = result.x[0]
        
    return ret
```

and, for plotting:

```py
x_values = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
y_true = objective_function_gp(x_values)

plt.plot(x_values, y_true, label="True Function")
plt.scatter(x_opt_newton, objective_function(x_opt_newton), color="red", label="Newton's Method")
plt.scatter(x_opt_gp, objective_function_gp(x_opt_gp), color="green", label="Gaussian Process")
```

where `objective_function_gp()` is the function you defined before.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried to apply it but I still get an empty plot and the following error. Apologies for the terrible formatting: ** File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:504 in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (1,)**

Comment: I tried to get the plot with this: x_values = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
y_true = [objective_function(x) for x in x_values]
plt.plot(x_values, y_true, label="True Function")
plt.scatter(x_opt_newton, objective_function(x_opt_newton), color="red", label="Newton's Method")
plt.scatter(x_opt_gp, objective_function(x_opt_gp), color="green", label="Gaussian Process")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("f(x)")
plt.title("Comparison of Optimization Methods")
plt.show(). Although, I get a plot this time, I can only see Newton on the plot but not the Gaussian Process.

Comment: Please change `objective_function()` to `objective_function_gp()` in `plt.scatter(x_opt_gp, ...)`, that will do.